# BGUI text becomes uncentered when setting full screen in game

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I have a game which makes use of the BGUI module for text input and also includes some labels.

Everything is working as intended when I don't do anything to change the window size (ignore that the text is too large!), as below:

[image: This is nice and centered!]

However, I want the window to be larger, ideally full screen. For this I have added `bge.render.setFullScreen(True)` to a bge script which is marked for execution before all other scripts. But when I do this, the result is the following:

[image]

The BGUI code for these labels is below:

```
class SimpleLayout(bgui.bge_utils.Layout):
    def __init__(self, sys, data):
        self.instructionlbl = bgui.Label(self, text='Provide the robot with a description of the location of the highlighted object', pos=[0, .9],
            sub_theme='Large', pt_size = 50,options = bgui.BGUI_DEFAULT | bgui.BGUI_CENTERX)
        self.titlelbl = bgui.Label(self, text=empty.getPropertyNames()[0], pos=[0, .95],
        sub_theme='Large', pt_size = 50,options = bgui.BGUI_DEFAULT | bgui.BGUI_CENTERX)
        self.figurelbl = bgui.Label(self, text='Figure: ',pos=[0, .85],
                sub_theme='Large',pt_size = 50, options = bgui.BGUI_DEFAULT| bgui.BGUI_CENTERX)
```

I have also tried avoiding setting fullscreen by using `bge.render.setWindowSize(bge.render.getDisplayDimensions()[0],bge.render.getDisplayDimensions()[1])`  instead but I get the same result.

Setting to fullscreen is also throwing off the cursor in the text input field, putting it one character behind.

Is there something wrong with the way I am using `bge.render.setFullScreen(True)`? Or is it something I need to fix with the BGUI parts? Any thoughts?